# Transifex string "Member for" in the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization, russian-stackoverflow

I would like to know which string (i.e. keys on [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/)) are used for strings in the "Member for" section of the profile page:

- > [image: 3month]

- > [image: 2y10m]
- etc...

We have some issues related to these strings on ruSO.

According to my investigation (via transifex data base) some [strings](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263235?key=e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27) use incorrect plural forms. E.g.

- "1 year, 3 months" // should use `years=one, months=few`, but `years=many, months=few` is used instead.
- "2 years, 1 month" // should use `years=few, months=one`, but `years=few, months=many` is used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following time strings are used with the various member for variants across the site (on the election page, user account info page, user page, and users list page):

- [`today`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=c5e7dfaf771d423ecf59b008369021e8)
- [`$__count$ days`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=151e08c767c86417dff98389b214c673)
- [`$years$ years, $months$ months`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=e39b362eccc2425b04d9ef53ad0a9c27)
- [`$years$ years, $months$ months ago`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=6b0d6ca383ca42c04a7dbc18231d80bb)
- [`$__count$ years`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=8113b72894900e6937e392cf092f07b8)
- [`$__count$ years ago`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=0b4355d1fd17cd35f535c3c4720941d5)
- [`$__count$ months`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=5e7ea9eb57c0eaaa8406cd0e2bfebf74)
- [`$__count$ months ago`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/-1?key=2d7e6dcadfb5db192a91540c2b6ee86e)

### Update

There was indeed a bug with the ordering of the variant conditions in our localization code, so it was correct in some cases and invalid in others. A fix is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2017.1.3.4401` on ruSO).

Comment: Did you test cases from the question?