# Localization issue for searching in help

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, localization, russian-stackoverflow

I [try to search](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) in help pages on ruSO and see that at least a couple of strings are not localized:

> [image: help search]

As far as I can see there are no untranslated strings `$count$ results` and `Privilege` in transifex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the missing localization - with you in the next build.

Comment: Could you please add keys for these strings from transifex here?

Comment: I don't have access to transifex.

Comment: You need to get it! For completeness it would be good to have links like [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289232/339911).